# calling function whose name is class name itself?

Tags: c++

I do not know what methodology they use since the code base is **huge**.

It defined a class like this:

```
class ABC {
    member_func(string c);
};

main() {
    ABC("").member_func("this random string");
}
```

What is the missing code that would enable us to call `ABC("");`?

I did not see any object of that class created anywhere.

Comment: there isnt a function or a functor defined.

Comment: Is that a function call or a constructor? It could be any of those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That simply constructs an object of type `ABC`, but doesn't initialize any permanent memory location with that object.  I.e., the initialized object the call to the `ABC` constructor creates is a temporary, and is lost after the call since it is not constructed in a memory location that can be accessed after the call such as an automatic variable on the stack, a static memory location, etc.  So the "missing" code to make a call like that usable in the "real-world" is to actual name an object that is constructed so that it can be accessed later... for example, something like `ABC my_object("");` or `ABC my_object = ABC("");`.

**UPDATE:** In the updated code you've posted, what's taking place is again a temporary object of type `ABC` is being constructed, and then a non-static method of class `ABC` called `member_func` is being called on the temporary that was created by the call to `ABC`'s constructor.  Of course for this code to have any meaning in the "real world", that call to `member_func` would have to contain some side-effect that would be visible outside of the class instance (i.e., the class instance could be containing a data-member that is a pointer to some shared memory object that the call then modifies).  Since though from the code sample you've posted there does not seem to be any side-effects from the call, it's for all intents and purposes a non-operation ... a temporary `ABC` class instance is created, it has a method called on the instance, and then any reference to the instance is lost since it was not constructed in a memory location accessible from the current scope of `main()`.

Comment: The actual call is not  ABC("");
Buts its ABC("").member_func();
Let me update that in the actuall question itself

Comment: After going down the bjarne stroustroup road, i figured that one of the subtle and VERY important concepts of C++ is **temporaries**.

Answer (score 3):

```
class ABC
{
    std::string d;
public:
    ABC(std::string x)         // For the ABC("").
    { d = x; } 

    void foo(std::string x)    // For the foo("").
    { std::cout << d << std::endl << x << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    ABC("This creates a temporary object.").foo("This calls foo().");

    // Is the same as...

    {
        ABC obj("This creates another object.");
        obj.foo("This calls obj.foo().");
    } // obj is destroyed.

    return(0);
}
```

Self explanatory... I hope. :)